# Jquery undefined on external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have the below function in an external js file:

```
var fuelEfficiency = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.getCarMakes = function() {

        // Dropdown element
        var select = $('.selMake');

    };

    return self;
};
```

And I a have another js file that uses the above function like so:

```
(function ($, FuelEfficiency) {

    var FE = new fuelEfficiency();

    $(document).ready(function ($) {

        FE.getCarMakes();

    });

})(jQuery, fuelEfficiency);
```

This gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" for the $('.selMake'). I tried wrapping the fuelefficiency function with jquery but that didn't work either. What can I do to get pass the jquery undefined issue?

Comment: was jquery included before the other file?

Comment: Yes, this is actually on wordpress. So yes jquery was registered and enqueued before.

Comment: If you have two files, where one is included after the other, you do not need to pass the $ variable. 

If you include jQuery in your head, then define your other file that uses jQuery straight after, it should be able to use it.

Can you give us the code that includes the files?

Why don't you get rid of the `(function($, FuelEfficiency) {})(jQuery, fuelEfficiency);`, and run the script like that? You could also get rid of the `function($)` and replace it with `function()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the answer. Seems like JQuery on wordpress is in a "compatibility mode" where the Jquery shortcut "$" won't work. You can read more about it [here](http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/). As per the post you would have to use "jQuery" in place of "$".

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to inject and alias `fuelEfficiency` as `FuelEfficiency` then make sure to use the latter inside the function:

```
(function ($, FuelEfficiency) {//note the case

    var FE = new fuelEfficiency();//note the case(should be FuelEfficiency)

    $(document).ready(function ($) {

        FE.getCarMakes();

    });

})(jQuery, fuelEfficiency);
```

Check your version of jQuery also.  The code you posted runs without errors. http://jsfiddle.net/xcn4bhx7/